# How to use lightning:formattedDateTime within lightning:helptext?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to create a dynamic [help text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext/documentation) within lightning component having formatted date time value.
But it seems it allow only text.

Current code:

```
 <lightning:helptext content="{!('Changed at' + case.Custom_DateTime_Field__c)}"  iconName="action:info"/>
```

Current Output showing datetime in "2020-07-10T15:08:47.000Z" format.
Can we change it to "2020-07-10 03:08 PM" ?

Is there any way to use [lightning:formattedDateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/example) with helptext ? Any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do formatting at the Apex level and pass the string to the lightning component.

Doc link - [Date Time class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_3)

**Code from doc-**

```
Datetime GMTDate = 
  Datetime.newInstanceGmt(2011,6,1,12,1,5);
String strConvertedDate = 
  GMTDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 
                 'America/New_York');
// Date is converted to 
// the new time zone and is adjusted
// for daylight saving time.
System.assertEquals(
  '06/01/2011 08:01:05', strConvertedDate);
```

Also, if you're not using Apex, you can think for JS controller for formatting. IMO, View portion should have only view functionality.